# Can't align text sections to two seperate ends. Axisalignment is either overriding or not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want that humidity and value to be separated into two ends. Start and End, I tried using mainAxisAlignment and crossAxisAlignment. But they aren't working. I don't want to use sizedboxes at all.

Maybe my upper column is overriding all the styles of other columns. Still, it isn't working. I'm really confused now

Here is the output of what i have right now:

[image: Imgur]

What i want:

[image: Imgur]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 60,
            ),
            // the header section which mostly contain cityname and the id status
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    'San Fransisco',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontSize: 33,
                        letterSpacing: 1),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    'Mostly Drizzle',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.grey[600],
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            SizedBox(
              height: 35,
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 30),
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0)),
                    elevation: 8,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(22.0),color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25, top: 40, bottom: 40),
                            child: Text(
                              '32°C',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                  fontSize: 30),
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  //here comes all the main json details wtf
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Humidity', style: mainText,),
                        SizedBox(width: 15,),
                        Text('Value')],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Humidity'),
                        SizedBox(width: 15,),
                        Text('Value')],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Humidity'),
                        SizedBox(width: 15,),
                        Text('Value')],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Humidity'),
                        SizedBox(width: 15,),
                        Text('Value')],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Humidity'),
                        SizedBox(width: 15,),
                        Text('Value')],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use TWO COLUMNS instead of tens of rows

Comment: Yeah. Sounds efficient. But i want to know why axisAlignment isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Problem you had:**

You weren't using `Expanded`, and you were also not setting

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
```

---

**Full Code:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 60),
          // the header section which mostly contain cityname and the id status
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                child: Text(
                  'San Fransisco',
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Ubuntu', fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 33, letterSpacing: 1),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 15),
                child: Text(
                  'Mostly Drizzle',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.grey[600],
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 35),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 30),
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0)),
                  elevation: 8,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0), color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25, top: 40, bottom: 40),
                        child: Text(
                          '32°C',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Ubuntu', fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 30),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded( // you need this
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    //here comes all the main json details wtf
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // add this
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Humidity'),
                          SizedBox(width: 15),
                          Text('81%'),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // add this
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Wind'),
                          SizedBox(width: 15),
                          Text('18 km/h'),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // add this
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Humidity'),
                          SizedBox(width: 15),
                          Text('23%'),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // add this
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Sunrise'),
                          SizedBox(width: 15),
                          Text('6:45'),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // and finally this
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Sunset'),
                          SizedBox(width: 15),
                          Text('17:20'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: One more thing! Do you have any suggestions or know about any good sources to learn flutter animations?

Comment: There are plenty of resources, you can learn it from official docs, medium blogs, YouTube videos etc. Would you mind accepting the answer :)

Comment: Already did, but due to low reputation. I can't add a point here.

Comment: I unlocked the privilege by accepting the answer. Lol XD

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `SizedBox` widget try the `Spacer` widget. Here is its [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html).

Comment: Do you know any reason why it's not working? Even after removing the axisalignment from top column. It isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `Row`

```
MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
```

eg

```
 Row(

     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
     children: <Widget>[
     Text('Humidity'),
     Text('Value')],
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set padding left to 25 and right to 30

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 30),
```

change this with

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 30),
```

[image]